# Counterexample to mostow rigidity theorem

Tags: reference-request, hyperbolic-geometry, 3-manifolds, rigidity

I am looking for an example of $M$ and $N$ two orientable hyperbolic complete without boundary 3-manifolds ( with infinite hyperbolic volume) such that $\pi_{1}M\cong \pi_{1}N$ but $M$ is not isometric to $N$.

Is there a concrete such example  ?

Comment: $\mathbb R^3$ and $S^2\times\mathbb R$?

Comment: @Wojowu afaik S^2 x R cannot have an hyperbolic complete structure.

Comment: I am ignorant of the subject, so perhaps this is silly. But a loxodromic transformation $\varphi$ of hyperbolic 3-space acts without fixed points, as does a parabolic transformation $\psi$. These isometries are not conjugate. This should imply that the resulting quotients $\Bbb H^3/\langle \varphi\rangle$ and $\Bbb H^3/\langle \psi\rangle$ should be both diffeomorphic to $S^1 \times \Bbb R^2$ but non-isometric. Have I made an error here?

Comment: @mme: You are correct.

Comment: Thank you for verifying. The next interesting question would be to construct non-diffeomorphic manifolds which both carry infinite-volume hyperbolic metrics. I am not sure if this is possible or not. I believe link complements are out: I half-remember that the only link complements with infinite volume complete hyperbolic metrics are the complements of the unknot and the Hopf link.

Comment: (Obviously in the comment above I meant for both manifolds to have the same fundamental group, or it has a tautological answer.)

Comment: @mme: It's easy already in the 2d case: one-hole torus and 3-holed sphere. In 3d this is also not hard, say, trivial and nontrivial interval bundles over genus 2 surface.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I believe there are many.

For example, if you think of hyperbolic $2$-space as a geodesic subspace of hyperbolic $3$-space, any group of hyperbolic isometries of hyperbolic $2$-space extends naturally to a group of hyperbolic isometries of hyperbolic $3$-space.

So if you take the fundamental group of a hyperbolic $2$-manifold, and embed it in this manner in the group of isometries of hyperbolic $3$-space, and take the quotient of hyperbolic $3$-space, you get a hyperbolic $3$-manifold of infinite volume such that the hyperbolic $2$-manifold is a totally geodesic submanifold. Topologically, it has the form $\Sigma \times \mathbb R$ but the metric is flared out away from $\Sigma \times \{0\}$ so that the manifold has infinite volume.

This is pretty much the tautological example.

For different hyperbolic metrics on $\Sigma$ you get different hyperbolic $3$-manifolds.